# Display AJAX Loader on submitting a from

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to display an ajax loader icon when user try to submit a form, and block the content of the page (Fade in).

I have this code, but it works wrongly, it display the loader icon before submitting the form and hide it after submitting the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction() {
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "?action=sms&pageaction=Send SMS", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}​
</Script>
```

And I have DIV :

```
<!---progress-->

<div id="content" > 
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <h1>Loading ... Please wait </h1>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <img src="image//loading.gif" />
    </div>

<!---progress-->
```

And the `submit` button is calling the `ajaxFunction()`

```
<input type="submit" name="pageaction"  class="send_sms" value="Send SMS" onclick="ajaxFunction()" />
```

Anybody please help me in correcting my code to make it work as follow:

1. display a transparent background to block the page while submitting the form.
2. display a loading icon.
3. Hide the transparent background and hide the loading icon.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `content` to hide. You can do that simply:

```
<div id="content" style="display:none;">
  ...
</div>
```

Put it visible before sending the AJAX request.

```
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";​​​​​​
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: It also seems he wants a [lightbox effect](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/).

Comment: Did not work  `xmlHttp.open("GET","?action=sms&pageaction=Send SMS",true);``document.getElementById("content").style.display= "block";`
        `xmlHttp.send(null);`

Comment: Check for errors. Also, I hope you didn't paste the HTML with the ellipsis.

Comment: I have pasted the line `document.getElementById("content").style.display= "block";` before `xmlHttp.send(null);` and change the display of content to none

Comment: Dear Alexander, now it works, but the loading image is just flash for a second and disappear although the page still loading

Comment: Your AJAX might be really fast then. I think you need to update your question to put more details. Try posting a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).